# how to restrict the table rights of certain tables for a certain user eventhough that user inherits from admin

Tags: sql, postgresql, roles, postgresql-9.3

I have a user called 'user1' inherited from admin(who have all access to all tables).Is there any way in postgres such that if logged in as
admin - all tables will be visible.But when logged in as 'user1'(though user1 inherited from admin) only a select few tables should be visible (so he can only open those, he cannot open a table which he cannot see)

Comment: If admin is superuser then you can't do this without revoking admin from user1. If he is not superuser, then you can use [RLS](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/ddl-rowsecurity.html) to block reading of certain rows for certain groups of roles. Then use [event trigger](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/event-triggers.html) to block `ALTER` on table. It seems like much easier would be to just manage permissions per role without inheriting AND/OR create certain groups with limited permissions and grant those for users.